# La république, une guillotine dans un crépuscule ; l’empire, un sabre dans la nuit

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Que veut dire le passage suivant:

> La république, l’empire, n’avaient été pour lui jusqu’alors que des mots monstrueux. La république, **une guillotine dans un crépuscule** ; l’empire, **un sabre dans la nuit**.

Source:[Les Miserables Tome III](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables/Tome_3/Livre_3/06)

Comment: Que comprends tu de ce passage ? Que cherches tu à comprendre exactement ? Tu souhaite de traduction ou une explication du texte ?

Comment: Une explication :)

Answer (score 3):

Cela signifie que Marius, jusqu'à ce qu'il ait lu le *Moniteur* ainsi que de nombreux ouvrages traitant de la République et de l'Empire, considérait la République comme n'ayant enfanté que de la guillotine et l'Empire comme un état de guerre permanente.

Comme il est dit dans la phrase suivante :

> Il venait d’y regarder, et là où il s’attendait à ne trouver qu’un chaos de ténèbres, il avait vu, avec une sorte de surprise inouïe mêlée de crainte et de joie, étinceler des astres, Mirabeau, Vergniaud, Saint-Just, Robespierre, Camille Desmoulins, Danton, et se lever un soleil, Napoléon. Il ne savait où il en était. Il reculait aveuglé de clartés.

Il s’aperçoit que la République et l'Empire représentent beaucoup plus de choses.